# What football match had on the playing field the highest number of golden ball (Ballon d'or) winners?

Tags: football, trivia

I was recently watching the highlights of the [2006 FIFA World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006_FIFA_World_Cup) Quarter-final between [France and Brasil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006_FIFA_World_Cup_knockout_stage#Brazil_vs_France). In that match [Zidane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zinedine_Zidane) was playing for France, and [Ronaldinho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronaldinho) and [Ronaldo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronaldo_(Brazilian_footballer)) for Brasil, all previous golden ball winners, and also [Kaka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kak%C3%A1), who will win the [golden ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballon_d%27Or) in 2007.

What is the football match that had on the field the highest number of golden ball winners? I did a quick google search, but nothing came up.

Answer (score 4):

The football match that I could find which had on the field the highest number of golden ball winners at that time is [Barcelona v/s Real Madrid Nov 20, 2004](https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/fc-barcelona_real-madrid/index/spielbericht/27991), which is ***4*** all from Real Madrid not counting future winners. Despite the presence of 4 golden ball winners Real Madrid lost the match 3-0.

From Barca :

1. **Ronaldinho*** (2005)
2. **Lionel Messi*** (On bench/Unused substitute, first in 2009)

From Madrid

3. **Ronaldo** (Brazilian)
4. **Luis Figo**
5. **Zinedine Zidane**
6. **Michael Owen** (Came as a substitute to David Beckham in 55 min)

Both Messi and Ronaldinho were actually future winners at that time.

Notable 2nd the 3rd runners up who were also present in the match are FCB (Xavi, Deco, Iniesta, Frank Rijkaard (Coach)), RM (Beckham, Roberto Carlos).

Comment: It had to be an el classico as both FCM and RM have won 21 Golden balls in total